# Scala - Pattern matching result of a for comprehension

Tags: scala, coding-style, pattern-matching, for-comprehension

I'm currently performing a pattern match on the result of a for-comprehension as follows

```
val validXsrf = for(
    cookie <- request.cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN"); 
    header <- request.headers.get("X-XSRF-TOKEN"); 
    if cookie.value == header ) yield true;

validXsrf match {
   case Some(true) => callbackFunc();
   case None       => throw new XsrfException();
}
```

However this feels a little overly verbose - is there a cleaner way of expression this?

Ideally I'd love to do something like

```
for(....) match { .... }
```

However this does not appear possible in Scala without wrapping the entire for-comprehension in brackets.

Is there a cleaner / more elegant way of expressing this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could abbreviate things a bit like this (assuming `callbackFunc` returns a `String`):

```
def validXsrf():String = {
  val xsrf = for{
    cookie <- request.cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN")
    header <- request.headers.get("X-XSRF-TOKEN") 
    if cookie.value == header
  } yield callbackFunc()

  xsrf.getOrElse(throw new XsrfException())
}
```

Now if you didn't want to throw the exception on the failure case, you could redefine the `validXsrf` method around returning a `Try` instead, something like this:

```
def validXsrf():Try[String] = {
  val xsrf = for{
    cookie <- request.cookies.get("XSRF-TOKEN")
    header <- request.headers.get("X-XSRF-TOKEN") 
    if cookie.value == header
  } yield callbackFunc()

  xsrf.fold[Try[String]](Failure(new XsrfException()))(Success(_))
}
```

Comment: Seems surprisingly obvious in hindsight. Thanks :)